# Google IAP Testing. Your order could not be processed. Please try again

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Testing our in app purchases using the test accounts leads to the dreaded "Your order could not be processed. Please try again". Did anyone solve this issue?
Our items have been active for a month, the test accounts are not linked to the developer account, and have valid credit card details.
Any help would be great
thanks

Comment: This is all we get as regards error messages. "[265] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/commitPurchase"

Comment: Yes, getting same issue, Was working couple of days ago but all of a sudden it started giving above mentioned issue.